# javascript comparing date formats

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I am trying to compare dates with different formats. I see wrong results when I compare the below, How can I converts dates to a standard format to get correct results.

[Heres my Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8pja2s1o/7/)

```
var date1 = "4/12/2018 9:52:21 PM";
    var date2 ="4/12/2018 9:52:51 PM";
    var date3 ="2018/04/12 21:54:40";
    var dateCondition1 = (date3>date2);
    var dateCondition2 = (date2>date1);
    alert(dateCondition1); //shows wrong result
    alert(dateCondition2); //shows right result
```

will this be a correct comparison?

```
var date1 = new Date("4/12/2018 9:52:21 PM");
var date2 =new Date("4/12/2018 9:52:51 PM");
var date3 =new Date("2018/04/12 21:54:40");
var dateCondition1 = (date3>date2);
var dateCondition2 = (date2>date1);
alert(dateCondition1); //shows wrong result
alert(dateCondition2); //shows right result
```

Comment: have a look at https://momentjs.com/, makes dealing with dates trivial

Comment: for what it's worth, you are comparing 3 strings, not dates. You'd need to parse the date strings into date objects to perform operations on them or compare them properly, all of which is again super easy with moment.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with pure javascript:

```js
var date1 = new Date("4/12/2018 9:52:21 PM");
var date2 =new Date("4/12/2018 9:52:51 PM");
var date3 =new Date("2018/04/12 21:54:40");
var dateCondition1 = (date3.getTime() > date2.getTime());
var dateCondition2 = (date2.getTime() > date1.getTime());
alert(dateCondition1);
alert(dateCondition2);
```

Answer (score 1):

in the first block of code you are comparing strings

```
"4/12/2018 9:52:21 PM" > "4/12/2018 9:52:21 PM";
```

in the second block of code the comparison is correct,

[image]

**Why does a boolean return in the comparison of 2 strings?**

"Matt Ball"

Because, as in many programming languages, strings are compared lexicographically.

You can think of this as a fancier version of alphabetical ordering, the difference being that alphabetic ordering only covers the 26 characters a through z.

**ALTERNATIVE**

using the library moment js is easier

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js"></script>
<script>
//Currrent Date
var now = moment(),
custom = moment('Mon 03-Jul-2017, 11:00 AM', 'ddd DD-MMM-YYYY, hh:mm A');
document.write("Compare dates=>" + now.isAfter(custom));
</script>
```

if you want to use the three comparisons you can format the dates as you want

```html
<html>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js"></script>
     <script>
     var now   = moment();
     var date1 = moment('4/12/2018 9:52:21 PM','DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss A');
     var date2 = moment('4/12/2018 9:52:51 PM','DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss A');
     var date3 = moment('2018/04/12 21:54:40','YYYY/DD/MM hh:mm:ss A');
     var dateCondition1 = (date3.isAfter(date2));
     var dateCondition2 = (date2.isBefore(date1));
     alert(dateCondition1);
     alert(dateCondition2);
     </script>
</html>
```